# How can I find the dimensions of an image on a responsive web page?

Tags: responsive-design

I am working as a graphic designer. They wanted me design some slider images on a page. But nobody knows the dimensions. I have seen that there are 4 different dimensions for an image when I inspect the page.

Large
Medium
Small
XSmall

So when you enter the website with a mobile phone Xsmall image appears..etc.

I have tried some ruler and responsive view extensions; but it didnt help me.

How can I find exact dimensions?

Comment: Are you looking for breakpoints?

Comment: you can do it with css or javascript, if you need more knowledge you can read twitter bootrstrap how works

Comment: @jpp Your edit looks pretty good however are you 100% sure that title edit is what OP is looking for?

Comment: @PeeHaa After re-reading it, I still think that's the intended interpretation, although there's certainly some room for ambiguity.

Comment: Yeah not sure... will wait for OP to clarify before approving or improving the edit

Comment: get the URIs of the images on disk. Download the images. Read the dimensions with your image viewer or editor (if not your browser already shows them to you if you open the images in a tab of its own)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact steps might depend on what browser you are using. Here are some instructions for Chrome (they will be similar for other browsers):

- Resize the window to get the image in the smallest dimensions.
- Right click the image and "Inspect Element"
- You will see a tab for "Computed". This indicates the computed CSS attributes for this image. From this view, you can read the height and width in pixels.
- Resize your window and repeat this for each of the image sizes.

A more advanced approach: depending on how they implemented responsive web design, you may be able to view the CSS the page is loading, and look for `@media` queries which control the size of the image depending on the viewport of the browser. Read more about `@media` [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).